# How to improve Postgres sql performance for transforming 5 million row flat file table into relational tables

Tags: postgresql

Apologies this is so contrived, but I think it gets the point across as to my needs.

I upload a flat file to a table that has a data structure like so.  5-10 million rows.

| id | zone | entity_type | code | parameters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | south | widget | "A" | plant_id "PlantA"; widget_id "Widget142"; |
| 2 | south | part | "B" | plant_id "PlantA"; widget_id "Widget142"; part_number "1"; |
| 3 | south | widget | "C" | plant_id "PlantX"; widget_id "Widget277"; |
| 4 | south | part | "D" | plant_id "PlantX"; widget_id "Widget277"; part_number "1"; |
| 5 | south | part | "E" | plant_id "PlantX"; widget_id "Widget277"; part_number "2"; |
| 6 | south | part | "F" | plant_id "PlantX"; widget_id "Widget277"; part_number "3"; |

You can see 'widgets', 'parts', and their attributes are all mixed together and have a many to many relationship (maybe this isn't apparent in my sample data here but a 'part' can be associated with multiple 'widgets'.  I want to parse these out into their own tables and then create a junction table.

Then I could write query to get the info I need in a format maybe similar to this:

| id | zone | code | widget_name | part_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | south | "B" | "Widget142" | 1 |
| 2 | south | "D" | "Widget277" | 1 |
| 3 | south | "E" | "Widget277" | 2 |
| 4 | south | "F" | "Widget277" | 3 |

Here is hopefully everything you need to see how I am performing the transformation myself.  It seems **very** slow.  Another point is that our database has 32 cores but does Postgres parallelize the query across the cores or is there something more I need to do for that?  I'm no DBA :)

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_raw(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    zone VARCHAR (100),
    entity_type VARCHAR (100),
    code VARCHAR (100),
    parameters VARCHAR (100)
);
INSERT INTO data_raw
VALUES
(1, 'south', 'widget', 'A', 'plant_id PlantA; widget_id Widget142'),
(2, 'south', 'part', 'B', 'plant_id PlantA; widget_id Widget142; part_number 1;'),
(3, 'south', 'widget', 'C', 'plant_id PlantX; widget_id Widget277'),
(4, 'south', 'part', 'D', 'plant_id PlantX; widget_id Widget277; part_number 1;'),
(5, 'south', 'part', 'E', 'plant_id PlantX; widget_id Widget277; part_number 2;'),
(6, 'south', 'part', 'F', 'plant_id PlantX; widget_id Widget277; part_number 3;');

-- select * from data_raw;

CREATE TABLE widget(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR (100),
    zone VARCHAR (100),
    plant_name VARCHAR (100),
    code VARCHAR (100),
    UNIQUE(name)
);

CREATE TABLE part(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    code VARCHAR (100),
    UNIQUE(code)
);

CREATE TABLE widget_part(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    widget_id INT,
    part_id INT,
    part_number INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (widget_id)
      REFERENCES widget (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (part_id)
      REFERENCES part (id),
    UNIQUE(widget_id, part_id)
);

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_widget_params;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_widget_params(
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        plant_id VARCHAR (100),
        widget_id VARCHAR (100)
    );

    INSERT INTO temp_widget_params
    SELECT 
       id, 
       parameters ->> 'plant_id' AS plant_id,
       parameters ->> 'widget_id' AS widget_id
    FROM (       
        SELECT r.id, 
                jsonb_object_agg(split_part(p.parm, ' ', 1), split_part(p.parm, ' ', 2)) AS parameters
        FROM data_raw r
            LEFT JOIN unnest(regexp_split_to_array(trim(';' FROM parameters), '\s*;\s*')) AS p(parm) ON true
        WHERE entity_type = 'widget'
        GROUP BY id
    ) x;

--  select * from temp_widget_params;
    
    INSERT INTO widget(name, plant_name, zone, code)
    SELECT              
        tp.widget_id, 
        tp.plant_id,
        r.zone,
        r.code
    FROM data_raw AS r 
        JOIN temp_widget_params AS tp
            ON r.id = tp.id
    ON CONFLICT ("name") DO NOTHING;  

--  select * from widget;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_part_params;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_part_params(
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        widget_id VARCHAR (100),
        part_number VARCHAR (100)
    );

    INSERT INTO temp_part_params
    SELECT 
       id, 
       parameters ->> 'widget_id' AS widget_id,
       parameters ->> 'part_number' AS part_number
    FROM (       
        SELECT r.id, 
                jsonb_object_agg(split_part(p.parm, ' ', 1), split_part(p.parm, ' ', 2)) AS parameters
        FROM data_raw r
            LEFT JOIN unnest(regexp_split_to_array(trim(';' FROM parameters), '\s*;\s*')) AS p(parm) ON true
        WHERE entity_type = 'part'
        GROUP BY id
    ) x;

--  select * from temp_part_params;

    INSERT INTO part(code)
    SELECT
        r.code
    FROM data_raw AS r
        JOIN temp_part_params AS pp
            ON r.id = pp.id 
    ON CONFLICT (code) DO NOTHING;

--  select * from part;

    INSERT INTO widget_part(widget_id, part_id, part_number)
    SELECT 
        w.id AS widget_id, 
        p.id AS part_id,
        CAST(tp.part_number AS INT)
    FROM (
        SELECT
            r.code,
            pp.widget_id,
            pp.part_number
        FROM data_raw AS r
            JOIN temp_part_params AS pp
                ON r.id = pp.id 
    ) AS tp
    JOIN part AS p
        ON tp.code = p.code
    JOIN widget AS w
        ON w.name = tp.widget_id
    ON CONFLICT (widget_id, part_id) DO NOTHING;    

-- example as to how the data might now be queried

    select 
        w.zone,
        p.code,
        w.plant_name,
        w.name,
        wp.part_number
    from widget_part as wp
    join widget as w
        on w.id = wp.widget_id
    join part as p
        on p.id = wp.part_id
    order by w.plant_name, wp.part_number;
```

Comment: Q: How much have you actually "done" (vs. "alternatives you're considering trying")?  Q: What exactly is "slow"? Reading the data from your flat file into the DB? Querying the DB?  Reading from "data_raw" into your myriad sub-tables?  Something else entirely?  Q: How frequently do you need to ingest these 5++M line flat files?  How long will you need to keep *ALL* the data for future reference?  This article might help: https://severalnines.com/database-blog/running-data-warehouse-postgresql

Comment: [Are mutliple client-based queries multithreaded internally in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301766/are-mutliple-client-based-queries-multithreaded-internally-in-postgresql), so you can split up your process per `code` and have those 6 pieces ("A" .. "F")  run at the same time...  But is that will makes thing quicker, depends on other factors to (like indexes)

Comment: Could you provide an example of what a few rows in the flat file look like? Also, is the number of parameters small(ish) and fixed? In this example, it seems that instead of `parameters` field, you'd want three fields `plant_id`, `widget_id`, `part_number`. And `part_number` might be NULL in many rows. Then, if you have all of this data into a large table, you could split it into smaller tables using `SELECT INTO`.

Comment: @paulsm4 I have completed the implementation in my example and do not have any alternatives at the moment.  Hopefully, this question will provide some alternatives for me to try.  Ingesting the flat file takes ~20min.  My query above took 8+ hours and timed out.  Files might be ingested a couple times a month.  All parsed data in widget, part, etc will be kept indefinitely but the staging tables could be dumped after parsing.

Comment: @bfris The first few rows of the flat file look exactly the same as the sample table I provided in my example.  It's just that it is a tab separated format.  I upload from the tsv to the table using psql COPY.  The fields in the parameters column can be fixed and hardcoded.

Comment: If you are comfortable with any scripting languages, you might consider reformatting the file to parse parameters into columns before COPY into PostgreSQL. It should be fairly quick.

Answer (score 0):

Additional information from your comments:

> - I upload from the tsv to the table using psql COPY.
> - Ingesting the flat file takes ~20min. My query above took 8+ hours and timed out
> - Files might be ingested a couple times a month. All parsed data in widget, part, etc will be kept indefinitely but the staging tables
>   could be dumped after parsing

It's unclear what performance issues you might have making queries once you've successfully ingested your data. Obviously, you'll want to think about adding "indexes" as soon as possible.

The immediate problem seems to be getting your data completely ingested.

SUGGESTIONS:

1. bfris made an excellent suggestion: consider [select into](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-selectinto.html) from your "raw_data".
2. Plan B: consider writing a script (Python, Java, C# - whatever language you prefer) that does the following:

   - Connects to your DB
   - Opens your flat file
   - Reads the file a line at a time
   - Parses the data columns, and inserts directly into each of the tables a row at a time

You'll no longer need the "raw_data" table at all.

It will take longer than "psql COPY"... but it just might resolve the problem!

Comment: Hi paulsm4 - please don't roll back good edits. The canonicals on Meta are fairly specific on this point - see [Should I remove 'fluff' (like greetings, signatures, "thanks", etc.) when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776) and [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160).

Comment: (There is much more leeway in comments, so if you want to add niceties there, you can do - though they will often be removed under the NLN (no longer needed) reason).

Comment: You'd be welcome to open a [chat session](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) with me, if you want to discuss - though I can't see the community's consensus on this theme changing any time soon, I'm afraid!